# Fetching all posts made by a user with Devise gem

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I'm using Devise to manage user model.

Here's the User model, user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  acts_as_voter
  has_many :topics

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable        

end
```

Here's the Topics model, topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voteable
    belongs_to :user
end
```

When I create a post, the user ID is stored in the "user_id" column of Topics. I want to a User profile page, which should display all the posts he has made. In my User profile page view, I have,

```
<%= Topic.find_by_user_id(@user.id) %>
```

I have two posts made by the same user,

[image: Topic]

But when I try fetch all the posts made by the user, the SQL command automatically queries with a LIMIT of 1. Like this,

[image: SQL]

And because of this, the view is fetching only 1 post made by the user. How do I fetch all the posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_by_attribute` will always return only one result. You need to change your code to:

```
Topic.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

or even better:

```
@user.topics
```